# Open-source firewall/router software (alternative to Kerio WinRoute)

Tags: router, firewall, open-source, software-rec, routing

I'm looking for an open-source alternative to Kerio WinRoute. Specifically, I want the PC running it to act as a firewall, router & bandwidth manager. Of the features I'm looking to use are:

- block/allow based on the usual set of tests (protocol, source/destination ip/port, etc)
- NAT & port redirection
- DHCP
- allocate a a certain minimum amount of guaranteed bandwidth to every PC on the network
- optionally, traffic stats

osalt.com doesn't have anything on either "kerio" or "winroute". Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally love and recommend [Monowall](http://m0n0.ch/wall/).

---

```
*  web interface (supports SSL)
* serial console interface for recovery
      o set LAN IP address
      o reset password
      o restore factory defaults
      o reboot system
* wireless support (access point with PRISM-II/2.5/3 cards, BSS/IBSS with other cards including Cisco)
* captive portal
* 802.1Q VLAN support
* stateful packet filtering
      o block/pass rules
      o logging
* NAT/PAT (including 1:1)
* DHCP client, PPPoE, PPTP and Telstra BigPond Cable support on the WAN interface
* IPsec VPN tunnels (IKE; with support for hardware crypto cards, mobile clients and certificates)
* PPTP VPN (with RADIUS server support)
* static routes
* DHCP server and relay
* caching DNS forwarder
* DynDNS client and RFC 2136 DNS updater
* SNMP agent
* traffic shaper
* SVG-based traffic grapher
* firmware upgrade through the web browser
* Wake on LAN client
* configuration backup/restore
* host/network aliases
```

Comment: That looks great, will take a closer look.

Comment: The absence of what they call "bounce" is a bit of a problem. I host a bunch of servers and I like to access them both internally and externally on the same URL. They suggest some tricks with DNS, but I wasn't planning to host any DNS services...

Comment: What you are looking for is NAT Loopback and I thought that it does support that :S

Answer (score 3):

i'm running a **[Smoothwall](http://www.smoothwall.org/)** box, probably the most powerful open source firewall available, right on par with BIG $$$ commercial products, and yet it is quite easy to manage.

another excellent alternative is **[Vyatta Community Edition](http://www.vyatta.org/)** ("a powerful network appliance that can run circles around proprietary systems"), it features routing, firewalling, VPN, intrusion prevention, and WAN load balancing services.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend IPCop available from http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ipcop/wiki

Answer (score 1):

Try untangle at http://home.untangle.com/G01 . It can be installed on windows so you won't require a dedicated box like solutions above would require.

Comment: Doesn't look like the right kind of tool for me - it doesn't say anything about routing for example. I _am_ actually looking for something to run on a dedicated box and do NAT and DHCP and stuff, to replace the router rather than work alongside it.

Comment: www.clarkconnect.com/ may be what you want.

Comment: Untangle also requires two network cards.

Answer (score 1):

Besides other great products like IPCop and monowall, there's [Endian FW](http://www.endian.com/en/community/feature-comparison/), available as community edition.